# How to assign function output array to smarty

Tags: php, arrays, printing, smarty

I have following php code inside .tpl file

```
{php}
   class Test
   {
      public function uname()
      {
         $key = array(
            'email' => '123@abc.com',
            'domain'   => 'example.com');
         return $key;
      }
      public function passwd()
      {
         return 'password123';
      }
   }
   $control = new Test();
{/php}
```

How can I print the output of $control->uname() & $control->passwd() function inside the .tpl file ?.

Comment: **Don't** put PHP code in the template file. Keep the logic (the PHP code) and the presentation (the Smarty template) separate.

Answer (score -1):

Assign the object to the Smarty global object first of all.

```
$smartyObject->assign('control-passwd', $control->passwd());
```

Then you can output it as you would normally

```
{$control-passwd}
```

Comment: This question is about [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template engine.